# Debug info from Ansible Custom Module?

Tags: python, ansible

I wrote my own Ansible module in Python. It is working fine, however
I would like to report some information during running task (task takes a long time). I know that after execution of task, `stdout` is written to console.

However, I would like to show some info during execution of task. Is it possible?

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible out of the box right now (Ansible 2.7). There's [proposal #92](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/92) for this.

But there's a way. I've talked about this concept during one of local meetups:

[image: out of band logging]

**Core idea:**

- Wait for log stream inside Ansible process on Control Host (using callback)
- SSH to Remote Host with backward tunnel
- Send logs to `localhost:9999`, so they are sent back to Control Host via tunnel and displayed  within Ansible process

**Source code:**

Available here: https://github.com/berlic/wrikemeetup

**Modules:**

Listening callback – `callback_plugins/async_debug.py`
Sending snippet (`send_msg`) – `module_utils/async_send.py`
Demo module –  `library/slow_mod.py`