# Printing command stdout on console during runtime

Tags: ansible

Sometimes I have to wait very long during running ansible command. For example such command can be executed 30 minutes for my module:

```yaml
- name: make project
  shell: make -j4 install
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_dir }}/build"
```

I would like to see the stdout of this command live, during runtime, not when the command has finished (I see the output when the command has finished, but I need responsiveness, so I'm not interested in something like -v, -vvv or -vvvv). Is it possible to force ansible to  print the output during running command (not to buffer it and not to print it at the end)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution for given problem I found is to redirect the output of the command to some temporary file. So it will be:

```yaml
- name: make project
  shell: make -j4 install 2>&1 >/tmp/compile_logs.txt
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_dir }}/build"
```

Then I can open in another window:

```bash
tail -f /tmp/compile_logs.txt
```

Comment: You could also redirect to a network socket like in [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773566/6771046) or implement a [mechanism for streaming logs from modules](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/92#issuecomment-506572064) or have a look into [Debug info from Ansible Custom Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448411/6771046).

Answer (score 2):

You can't print the output while the command runs, but you can print it after the command finished:

```yaml
- name: make project
  shell: make -j4 install
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_dir }}/build"
  register: out
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: print output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"

- name: fail when make failed
  fail:
    msg: "make task failed"
  when: out.rc != 0
```

The `ignore_errors: yes` and the fail-task are there, so the output will get printed before your play fails in case the make-task fails.

You should also consider using the [make module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/make_module.html) instead of running `make` in a `shell`.