# How to run ansible playbook and see if a task running a script is waiting at a prompt?

Tags: ansible

When I run a script in Ansible, if it pauses to prompt for something, I am not seeing that prompt (e.g., `tar -xvf sometarball.tar`).  It prompts to say it is there already and asks to overwrite it with `y/n`.

Yes, I have ways to deal with that, but I was curious if there was a way I could have seen when I run the playbook that it was sitting at a prompt waiting for something?

Using `-v[vvv]` does not seem to help.  I found it by going on the VM and running the script manually.

Comment: Your global problem, i.e. responding to prompts in commands you launch: use the [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html). Your specific problem, i.e. having a prompt fired when using tar in the command line: apply good ansible practice and refrain from using shell/command when there is a module already doing the job for you. In this specific case, use the [`unarchive` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html)

Comment: And no, there's no way to see the output of the current command on the controller until that command has returned. Meanwhile, any shell/command that hangs longer than what seems acceptable should potentially let you think a prompt is waiting for an answer (among other problems that should be investigated on the target as well).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have used the unarchive_module. This particular case there is a lot of stuff that needed to get done that justified a shell script that happens to have a tar command in it.  It looks like the excepted answer is that there is no way to see the current command output and just expect that if it does not return and there is no error, expect that it is sitting at a prompt most likely.

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to run Ansible playbook and see if a task running a script is waiting at a prompt?***

It depends. According [Introduction to modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/modules_intro.html) and [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *Ansible executes each module, usually on the remote managed node, and collects return values.*

and

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable ...*

therefore such live output is not implemented. See also [How to display realtime `shell` `stdout`](https://serverfault.com/a/972664/448950)?

> *"Real time" or "streaming" output has not been merged to Ansible yet. The [original issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887) was closed in 2014 as not feasible. A [more recent proposal](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/92) has no major updates since February 2018.*

But there is a way if [Debugging Custom Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448411/6771046) or as workaround [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773566/6771046)

**Similar Q&A**

- [How can I get the output of an Ansible play as it is being run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341703/6771046)
- [Ansible: Run `shell` command with `async` module to capture its output on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75295004/)

---

> ***It prompts to say it is there already and asks to overwrite it with `y/n`. ... I found it by going on the VM and running the script manually.***

A good script for usage in enterprise environments should have the capabilities for unattended automated run, provide capabilities to configure such runs, answer files, documentation and so on.

If such isn't available a manual test before, tweaking and patching the script for enterprise usage might be an option and the less costly solution.