# Display logs from other jobs using async_status

Tags: automation, module, ansible

I have a task with a script (using the `ansible.builtin.expect` module for interactive script execution) and using `ansible.builtin.async_status` for script execution status.

But is there a way to display the script output in every retry instead of the below messages?

```bash
TASK [Wait for the script execution] *******************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (100 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (99 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (98 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (97 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (96 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (95 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (94 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (93 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (92 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (91 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (90 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (89 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (88 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (87 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [SERVER1]: Wait for the script execution (86 retries left).
```

Sample playbook content

```yaml
    - name: Execute Shutdown Script
      ansible.builtin.expect:
        command: "./{{ script_file }}"
        responses: "{{ responses }}"
      args:
        chdir: "{{ script_path }}"
      register: script_status
      async: 1000
      poll: 0
      changed_when: not script_status.changed
      

    - name: Wait for the script execution
      ansible.builtin.async_status:
        jid: "{{ script_status.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: script_job_async_result
      until: script_job_async_result.finished
      retries: "{{ script_async_retries | default(100) }}"
      delay: "{{ script_async_delay | default(1) }}"
      when: script_status.ansible_job_id is defined
```

Comment: You may have a look into [How can I get the output of an Ansible play as it is being run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341703/6771046), especially [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773566/6771046) and the comments under [Run `shell` command with `async` module to capture its output on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75295004/).

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no point in running a task asynchronously to poll its status synchronously just in the next task. You would get the same without `async` if the task you run supports `retries`.

Second, what you're asking it's not possible unless you use or implement a custom callback plugin - the `name` doesn't get updated on every retry. You can try to play with [`diy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html) callback plugin. There are examples for this exact problem in [Ansible issue #32584](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32584) on GitHub.

Without using non-default callback plugins, the only trick available to somehow indicate the progress in `FAILED - RETRYING ...` message with a variable in task `name` is to run several tasks - it would make sense if the task result contained multiple custom statuses that change over time. That's typically the case when you trigger some APIs running long complex operations.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Yeah I was checking around if any "workaround" :)