# Redirect output of command on remote host to a local file efficiently

Tags: linux, ansible

Consider the following command:

```
ssh root@host ./script_that_produce_large_output /dev/stdout > /tmp/local_file
```

I am trying to achieve the same using ansible, however when trying the simple approach of simply run the command then register the output and write it to a file using copy module, its having trouble with large outputs obviously because it is stored in memory of the remote server. the first command isnt storing in memory it simply has high CPU usage which I'd prefer.

example ansible playbook that results in a MemoryError:

```
- name: Stdout to local file
  hosts: 192.168.206.132
  tasks:
    - name: print
      command: ./script_that_produce_large_output /dev/stdout
      register: output

    - name: Save to file locally
      copy:
        content: "{{ output.stdout }}"
        dest: /tmp/local_file
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Now, ofcourse I could tweak something that will utilize sshpass inside the ansible playbook, but I was wondering if there was any ansible approach for that. thanks
Any insights/suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I wonder if using [`async` with `poll: 0`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0) (as if you would like to run this in // with something else) could work around your problem... It might force storing the result on disk on the target before you later retrieve it. Give it a try. If this does not work, then the easiest solution is to store the result in file yourself on the target, fetch it and delete it.

Comment: @Zeitounator I dont want to store in target disk at all since it might also cause problems, what I'm looking for is a client-server approach for transfering data using an ansible playbook so I dont have to create something custom.

Comment: The problem here is basically that your are trying to use a caterpillar mechanic shovel to stir sugar in a coffee cup: it's the wrong tool. Since a basic ssh connection with redirection is doing exactly what you wish why don't you stick to that? Although it's normally not a good practice, you can even launch this in an ansible `shell` task delegated to localhost since your have a very particular need. Note that if you feel storing even temporarily some files on a target is a problem, you should not use Ansible at all since this is how it functions under the hood anyway.

Comment: @Zeitounator then what should I use? consider Id rather not do custom scripts because it should be organized and part of a pipeline.

Comment: I have never tried it, but I am wondering if the RAW module would be a possible solution?

Comment: Another option would be to make your Ansible controller into an NFS server as well. Mount the share on the target machine as the first task. Then write the output of the script to that mount point.  I actually do this for installing specific software.  The software installs quicker running it from the NFS mount then pushing over the software in a Gzip file, decompressing it and then running the installer.

Comment: @Squashman I thought about doing it using the mount module for example but that feels a lil bit unsecure since for the target server to access the mount you have to specify credentials and then have to ensure the mount is deleted from the system, isnt that prone to errors?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that if the `register output` method fails due to size there **is** no efficient way of getting the file other than writing it to a remote file, `fetch`ing that file and then deleting it (`file`, `state: absent`) on the remote end; a three-step process.

Comment: what I mean is its not necessarily a file, but a command large output so if I can somehow redirect that output to a remote location like with ssh(which only consumes cpu because it transfers in chunks) in an ansible-way would be great

Comment: That's what I was saying. If your output blows out the memory when trying to store capture it in RAM a file is the only solution. @Almog

Comment: no, you dont have to store it in a file you could simply store a bit of it in RAM every time (which is how SSH protocol works, transfer in chunks) as the first command in my post

Comment: @Almog - but you said you get memory errors doing that. So you really **can't** use that method, elegant as the approach might be.

Comment: nono the method I first gave is great since it does not occur a MemoryError unlike using ansible 'register' and then save it, my question is really how to do the code I gave in the first example inside an ansible playbook

Comment: I'm not talking about the manual pipeline; I'm talking about registering the output in ansible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are observing is the expected behavior because of the nature of Ansible and Distributed Computing in that specific case.

A workaround could be streaming the output back during execution as shown under

- [Debug info from Ansible Custom Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448411/6771046)
- [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341703/6771046)

An other might be to simply `KEEP_REMOTE_FILES`

- [Ansible Configuration Settings - `DEFAULT_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-keep-remote-files)

fetch them after task execution and post-process or analyze them on the Control Node.

A third option regarding

> *... somehow redirect that output to a remote location ... in an ansible-way would be great*

could be to tweak the Module Source code in question with an option to do Remote Logging, register the output in a log file on the Remote Node. In your example, [`command.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/command.py) and [`shell.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/shell.py).